# NextJs script component should hide on a specific page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my React/NextJS app I added a new component to show a FreshDesk widget.

This component should only show on some specific pages after a login but when I logout from the app the widget is still visible until I refresh the page

The component

import Script from 'next/script';

```
const FreshDesk = () => {
  const { freshDesk } = useConfig();
  return (
    <>
    {console.log(freshDesk)}
      <Script
        src={`https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/${freshDesk}.js`}
        strategy="lazyOnload"
      />

      <Script id="my-script" strategy="afterInteractive">
        {` window.fwSettings={
                'widget_id':${freshDesk},
              };
              !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
            `}
      </Script>
    </>
  );
};

export default FreshDesk;
```

It is just called `<FreshDesk />` when it needs it.

The login page doesn't have the widget call but soon as I log out the widget is still there until I refresh and don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Did you try to disable the lazy load of the script ?  I suppose with lazy load, when useEffect() runs after mount, window.FreshworksWidget is still undefined.

Comment: I fixed already using a different approach I'll share my answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use `FreshworksWidget("destroy")` to destroy the widget.

[source](https://developers.freshdesk.com/widget-api/#introduction)

I would propose you add the following `useEffect` (disclaimer: I don't know the  library so this might not work perfectly)

```
useEffect(()=>{
  // create the widget if the script is loaded already
  if(window.FreshworksWidget){
     window.FreshworksWidget("boot");
  }
  // when unmounting the component, destroy the FreshworksWidget
  return ()=>{
    if(window.FreshworksWidget){
       window.FreshworksWidget("destroy");
    }
  }
  
}, []);
```

Comment: The problem here is that `window.FreshworksWidget` doesn't exist is giving an error using it like this

Comment: Seems this above doesn't work unfortunate

Comment: Actually worked I had for some reason to rebuild the app to have it work

Comment: Never mind not working still now is doing the opposite I have to refresh to see the widget that useEffect gives that now :(

Answer (score 0):

Decided to answer my own question by showing the solution I found working for me.

What I did was to add in the `login` component this code

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (document.querySelector('#launcher-frame')) {
      document.querySelector('#launcher-frame').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

and in the component, I was using the widget

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (document.querySelector('#launcher-frame')) {
      document.querySelector('#launcher-frame').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }, []);
```

In this way, I just hide it from my login page but showing everywhere else

Comment: Definitely not a clean solution, but  as long as DOM node mounts correctly it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to destroy freshwork widget is this way.  im using angular14 and it worked for me

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2, Inject  } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

 constructor(
    private _renderer2: Renderer2,  @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document) { }

ngOnDestroy() {
    let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.text = `      
         if(window.FreshworksWidget){
          window.FreshworksWidget("destroy")
         }
   `;
    this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script)
    }
```